# Alternatives to ImageMagick for PDF downsizing

Tags: php, linux, pdf

Having an issue with some PDF files not displaying properly in our iPad app.  I have come to the conclusion that we are needing to standardize by "converting" PDF to PDF.  I have successfully processed this using ImageMagick to convert the PDF to PNG (resized), and then pushing the PNG(s) back into a PDF.  However, something within ImageMagick is making photos within PDFs display wrong.  Same issue just converting a JPG or other graphic to PDF in ImageMagick.  I solved that by taking the output of the converted ImageMagick file and converting it again using GD to PNG, then pushing it through our PDF converter.

So my question is this:  What other PHP workflows would work with this, other than using ImageMagick for the conversion back to PDF?  We are not opposed to a paid solution, we just need something that works.  Our server runs centOS.

Comment: How are you creating the PDFs to begin with?

Comment: They are being created by our clients under a variety of scenarios.  We don't feel like we can impose a restriction on the way they create the PDF file, so we are trying to "standardize" anything they throw into the system to a format that the iPad will play nicely with.

Comment: Oh my.  So there's no pattern on what the iPad's PDF routines do and don't like, with regard to document creators?  Hmph.  Well, I suppose it doesn't change my shot in the dark...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut instinct, other than yelling at whoever wrote the PDF reader that you're suffering with, would be to [convert the PDF to PostScript using pdftops](http://stefaanlippens.net/pdf2ps_vs_pdftops), then [convert it back into a PDF using Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/cvs/Ps2pdf.htm).  You can enable a number of document compatibility options at that point, which may make it more digestible.

While this may have side effects, they should be minimal.  PDFs are basically a wrapper around a PostScript document, and it looks like pdftops can not do utterly stupid things during the conversion process.

This *may* break or simply not work with advanced PDF features, like digital signatures or forms.

Comment: I will give that a shot, thanks.  Upon further investigation, it looks like the iPad will display correctly if we can get the document to have a proper page size (8.5 x 11 or legal).  However, when converting PDF to PNG, the PDF is created based on the downscaled dimensions of the image instead of conforming to a page size.  Is there any way to get a PDF to conform to a page size instead of the physical dimensions of the image within?

Comment: If I were creating that programatically, I'd do it by creating a page of the proper size, then placing the image on the page directly, with the proper scaling.  However, I don't know how to actually resize pages in existing documents.  It might be possible to extract the images and manually recreate the page, but that might be messy...